# Apply WHERE Condition inside inner query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

We are using Entity Framework LINQ Query with joins and also group JOIN , inorder to use LEFT JOIN in the following LINQ expression

```
var queryable = 
from specificComponent in access.Plastics
join component in access.Components on specificComponent.ComponentId equals component.ComponentId
join cc in access.ComponentCompositions on specificComponent.ComponentId equals cc.ComponentId into ccGroupJoin
join offer in access.ProductOffers on component.BillOfMaterialId equals offer.BillOfMaterialId
join productRequestGroup in access.productRequestGroups on offer.productRequestGroupId
equals productRequestGroup.productRequestGroupId
join productRequest in access.productRequests on productRequestGroup.productRequestId
equals productRequest.productRequestId
join apd in access.AssignedProducts on productRequest.AssignedProductId equals apd.AssignedProductId
join pd in access.Products on apd.ProductId equals pd.ProductId

where productRequest.SupplierId == supplierId && component.TypeId == 20
from subset in ccGroupJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ItemDTO()
{
    CategoryId = specificComponent.CategoryId,                  
    OfferId = offer.OfferId,
    Type = subset.Type
};
```

> The problem is EF applies the WHERE CLAUSE in the LEFT JOIN instead of
>   inner query. It degrades the performance heavily.

EF Generated Query

```
SELECT [Filter1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId]
    ,[Filter1].[OfferId] AS [OfferId]       
    ,[Extent8].[Type] AS [Type]
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId]
        ,[Extent1].[ComponentId] AS [ComponentId1]
        ,[Extent3].[OfferId] AS [OfferId]
        ,[Extent5].[SupplierId] AS [SupplierId1]
    FROM [dbo].[Plastic] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Component] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ComponentId] = [Extent2].[ComponentId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductOffer] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[BillOfMaterialId] = [Extent3].[BillOfMaterialId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductRequestGroup] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ProductRequestGroupId] = [Extent4].[ProductRequestGroupId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductRequest] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[ProductRequestId] = [Extent5].[ProductRequestId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AssignedProduct] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[AssignedProductId] = [Extent6].[AssignedProductId]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[ProductId] = [Extent7].[ProductId]
    WHERE 20 = [Extent2].[TypeId]  
    ) AS [Filter1]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ComponentComposition] AS [Extent8] ON [Filter1].[ComponentId1] = [Extent8].[ComponentId]
WHERE [Filter1].[SupplierId1] = 120
```

> Expected for good performance WHERE 20 = [Extent2].[TypeId]  AND
>   [Extent5].[SupplierId] = 120

We tried ordering the LINQ Expression to get the query with above where clause applied in inner result. But no luck, EF generates where in outer query only, i.e in LEFT JOIN and affects the performance badly.

Any idea, how this WHERE can be moved inside?

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL, nor should it be used as if it were. LINQ works on top of an ORM, in this case EF. It's the *ORM*'s job to generate joins from the relations between entities. Instead of trying to indirectly affect the generated query create proper entities and relations and let EF do the joins

Comment: In fact, if you wrote the SQL statement directly you wouldn't need an inner query, you'd just add the `LEFT JOIN` clause after all the `INNER JOIN` ones

Comment: You might be better off encapsulating it in a stored procedure or view and pointing entityframework at those.